# Changing data label in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I'm here because I have not find the way to change the display units the way I wanted.

For example, for Millions the system shows M.   But I want to show MM instead.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't**

---

In Power BI Desktop your options are limited to:

[image]

You're not the only to be bothered by this though.
There's an improvement issue in the Power BI forum here: 
[Customize the Display Units property in a visual](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/32596948-customize-the-display-units-property-in-a-visual). If you're a registered user you should definitely leave your vote there.